# Feign URL encoder query params

Tags: java, feign

I have a query param that's a secret and contains characters like `!, *, '` and feign is interpreting these characters, so they become like `%027`. The server doesn't expects the URL encoded and authentication fails, there is some way to Feign ignore and doesn't encode my query params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Feign provides by default is a `decodeSlash` property for `@RequestLine` annotation but that will only work for encoding `/`: `@RequestLine(value = "GET /auth/{param_with_/_character}", decodeSlash = false)`.

In your case, you will need to provide your own instance of Feign's [Contract](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Contract.java).

Beware that sending authentication in the URL may not be the best solution from a security point of view - it is more common to use HTTP body for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about authentication in URL vs body. Unfortunately the system that provides authentication isn't ours, so we can't make any change or PR for the authentication team :(